# Linked artes explanation

Tags: tales-of-xillia

With regard to my main character: Is it only possible to perform a linked arte  with my first-set arte (the one that I put in the first position on arte menu which I activate by pressing only 'O') or is it possible to make linked artes with the artes in other positions (the others that I activate using the analog sticks)?

Also, regarding the linked parter:  Can I choose which arte is he/she going to use on linked arte or must he always use the first one, too? In this case, how do I perform different combinations? Is it always necessary to enter the artes menu change the first one?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, linked artes apply to any you have set.  The thing to note, though, is that not every arte has a link with every character; they each have their own unique combinations.  So if you're playing Jude, you can link Steel with Milla or Leia, and they both do different things.  Linking with Milla causes a rather decent sized fireball centered on Jude, and when linking with Leia, causes a pulse that gives every friendly character that buff.

For linked artes, it takes two specific artes to create a linked arte.  When you see the link symbol, that means your partner will perform the required arte to create the link.  Since AI controlled characters have access to their entire repitoire of artes, there's no need to set anything at all for them, other than ensuring their artes are enabled.

Comment: Thanks, man! Nice answer! Only one more doubt: I didn't understand very well how the Chain Art works.. can you help me?

Comment: Feel free to ask a question about that!

Comment: How does it really works? And another thing, about the 5 segments of arts bar: I have noticed that sometimes I complete one segment without the "sword icon" start blinking.. In other words, sometimes I fill one segment without the chance to perform a link art =(